# Can we use front camera in two apps concurrently in android?

Tags: android

I want to record a video call made on skype on android phone. But when the call gets connected i start my app which record the video. But it troughs an error (My app cant start recording) "java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service"

Answer (score 3):

The camera can only be used by one application at a time.

As per the [`open()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#open(int)) documentation:

> Creates a new Camera object to access a particular hardware camera. If the same camera is opened by other applications, this will throw a RuntimeException.

Comment: Ok . But can we read the video stream from the front camera of phone while the skype call is going on through my app?

Comment: No, that would require acquiring and opening your own connection to the camera while it is already in use.

Answer (score 1):

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html states the following:
Accessing cameras

If you have determined that the device on which your application is running has a camera, you must request to access it by getting an instance of Camera (unless you are using an intent to access the camera).

> To access the primary camera, use the Camera.open() method and be sure
>   to catch any exceptions, as shown in the code below:
>
> ```
> /** A safe way to get an instance of the Camera object. */
> public static Camera getCameraInstance(){
>     Camera c = null;
>     try {
>         c = Camera.open(); // attempt to get a Camera instance
>     }
>     catch (Exception e){
>         // Camera is not available (in use or does not exist)
>     }
>     return c; // returns null if camera is unavailable
> }
> ```

**// Camera is not available (in use or does not exist)**

So, simply said, your answer is no.